# A continuous function $f$ on $E \subset \partial D$ is uniformly approximated by polynomials.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $\partial D$ is the unit circle and $E$ is a compact subset of $\partial D$ but $E \neq \partial D$. Given the following result is true: If $\mu$ is a complex Borel measure on $\partial D$ and
\begin{equation}
\int_{\partial D} e^{int} d\mu(t)=0
\end{equation} for $n=1,2,\ldots$, then either $\mu=0$ or the support of $\mu$ is $\partial D$. Use this result to prove that a continuous function $f$ on $E$ is uniformly approximated by polynomials. I have thought how to use this result for a few days but I failed. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: How much functional analysis are you allowed to use? I can think of an argument making the result a “direct” consequence of the admitted claim, but it’s using two major (and nontrivial!) functional analysis results.

Comment: @Mindlack, Theory of $H^p$ spaces can be used, but not Mergelyan's Theorem.

Comment: No idea what these are. I was thinking of Hahn-Banach and Riesz-Markov.

Comment: @Mindlack, I know Hahn-Banach Theorem and Riesz-Markov Theorem. Could you tell me how you these results?

Answer (score 1):

By Hahn-Banach (see the first application in [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn–Banach_theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem) ), if the polynomial functions are nondense for the uniform norm topology on $C(E)$, there is a linear form $\phi$ on $C(E)$ vanishing at every polynomial. By Riesz-Markov ( [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz–Markov–Kakutani_representation_theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) ), $\phi$ is the integral against a nonzero finite complex-valued Borel measure $\mu_1$ on $E$.

We can extend said measure to a measure $\mu$ on $\partial D$ with support in $E$, and by construction $\int{P \cdot d\mu}=0$ for any polynomial $P$ (ie $\mu(\cdot)=\mu_1(\cdot \cap E)$).

The complex exponentials are polynomials, so their integrals against $\mu$ is zero as well. By the result, the support of $\mu$ is $\partial D$ in full, but that’s a contradiction as its support is in $E$.

Comment: What is the statement of the Hahn-Banach and Riesz-Markov Theorem?

Comment: @KK Wong: I added links.

Comment: I see. They are two theorems, not one theorem. Thanks!

Comment: @Mindlack, I don't really get your point. I mean how I can apply the two theorems to show that if a continuous function $f$ cannot be uniformly approximated by polynomials on $E$, then a nonzero finite (complex) Borel measure on $E$ exists and its integral against any polynomial is zero.